# What is the difference between VS Code and the "Code" package on the Arch Linux packages website?

Tags: visual-studio-code

From my research, I've come across some conflicting information:

I first saw the mention of "code" [on the Arch Linux packages website](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/code/). It appears that "code" is a package available in the Arch Linux community repository. [The package size is approximately 14.3 MB](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/code/). I installed it and it looks exactly like VS Code.

I've conducted some online research to understand the differences between VS Code and Code. I referred to several sources, including StackShare [1](https://stackshare.io/stackups/visual-studio-code-vs-vscodium), [2](https://stackshare.io/stackups/visual-studio-code-vs-xcode), and [3](https://stackshare.io/stackups/github-vs-visual-studio-code), and [a page on the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Visual_Studio_Code). However, the information I found was either incomplete or ambiguous, leaving me uncertain about the exact differences between the two tools. Therefore, I'm seeking further guidance and a comprehensive explanation.

Please note that while the provided search results mention VSCode, VSCodium, Xcode, and GitHub, none of them specifically address a tool called "Code." Therefore, the lack of information on "Code" makes it difficult to provide a precise comparison. It's possible that "Code" refers to a different tool or may not have been mentioned in the search results provided. Further clarification or additional context would be helpful in order to address the difference between VS Code and Code more accurately.

Comment: the description says it all _The Open Source build of Visual Studio Code (vscode) editor_, it is a kind of VSCodium

Comment: You may want to see the details of VSCode vs VSCodium, here is a good starter: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167400/license-visual-studio-code-or-vscodium. It seemd "code" is another such projects aiming at having a truly free VSCode clone that doesn't bundles spyware (aka "telemetry") nor an abusive license.

Answer (score 1):

The page https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/code/ says

> Description:  The Open Source build of Visual Studio Code (vscode) editor
> Upstream URL: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode

which reads pretty clearly to me that it's a build of VS Code. You can find the instructions for building and running VS Code at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute.

See also [this comment from @chrisdias (a member of the VS Code team)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60#issuecomment-161792005), which they wrote:

> The cool thing about all of this is that you have the choice to use the Visual Studio Code branded product under our license or you can build a version of the tool straight from the `vscode` repository, under the MIT license.
>
> Here's how it works. When you build from the `vscode` repository, you can configure the resulting tool by customizing the [`product.json`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/product.json) file. This file controls things like the Gallery endpoints, “Send-a-Smile” endpoints, telemetry endpoints, logos, names, and more.
>
> When we build Visual Studio Code, we do exactly this. We clone the vscode repository, we lay down a customized `product.json` that has Microsoft specific functionality (telemetry, gallery, logo, etc.), and then produce a build that we release under our license.
>
> When you clone and build from the `vscode repo`, none of these endpoints are configured in the default `product.json`. Therefore, you generate a "clean" build, without the Microsoft customizations, which is by default licensed under the MIT license (note, i made [this commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/9dd095c27ea79f526b054f741bb52fa62fae80a9) to help make this more clear).

That's probably something along the lines of you're looking at in this Arch package: a build of VS Code, and is what [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/) is.

The difference is what `product.json` they use for the build. If you click [the "Source Files" link](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-community/tree/packages/code/trunk) in the right sidebar of [the page you linked](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/code/), you'll see [a file called product_json.diff](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-community/blob/packages/code/trunk/product_json.diff), which just looks to me like a patch on top of [the default product.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/product.json).

Also, I'm not surprised that you're seeing a package manager use "code" as an alias for VS Code. on the Snap store, VS Code is registered as "code". https://snapcraft.io/code.